# Compilation success even with error messages

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play-services

I'm implementing location services as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). My application compiled and runs like a charm but Intellij keeps giving this strange error message:

> Class '[my class]' must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract method 'onConnected()' in 'ConnectionCallbacks'

[image]

When I go to the declaration of the **ConnectionCallbacks** I see following:

```
static interface ConnectionCallbacks {
    void onConnected();

    void onDisconnected();
}
```

Which is incorrect, because when I do the same with the sample application from Google I see the following:

```
static interface ConnectionCallbacks {
    void onConnected(android.os.Bundle bundle);

    void onDisconnected();
}
```

I can't figure out why this is happening only with my project.

Comment: Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`, restart the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the editor reports errors, but the code compiles fine, most likely IDE caches are corrupted. You should do `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart the IDE.